# Can you pass by reference while using the ternary operator?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

Simple question, simple code. This works:

```
$x = &$_SESSION['foo'];
```

This does not:

```
$x = (isset($_SESSION['foo']))?&$_SESSION['foo']:false;
```

It throws `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '&'`. Is it just not possible to pass by reference while using the conditional operator, and why not? Also happens if there's a space between the `?` and `&`.

Comment: Which PHP version? 

AFAIU, with PHP 5.3 you can use: $x = &($_SESSION['foo']) ?: false;

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally snipped it out; 5.2.8, sadly.

Comment: @Milan That will trigger an E_NOTICE if the $_SESSION['foo'] element does not exist

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simple answer: no. You'll have to take the long way around with if/else. It would also be rare and possibly confusing to have a reference one time, and a value the next. I would find this more intuitive, but then again I don't know your code of course:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['foo'])) $_SESSION['foo'] = false;
$x = &$_SESSION['foo'];
```

As to why: no idea, probably it has to with at which point the parser considers something to be an copy of value or creation of a reference, which in this way cannot be determined at the point of parsing.

Comment: As [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) states: `Note: Please note that the ternary operator is a statement, and that it doesn't evaluate to a variable, but to the result of a statement. This is important to know if you want to return a variable by reference.`

Answer (score 23):

In the very simply case, this expression, which is illegal;

```
$c = condition ? &$a : &$b; // Syntax error
```

can be written like this:

```
$c = &${ condition ? 'a' : 'b' };
```

In your specific case, since you're not assigning by reference if the condition is false, a better option seems to be:

```
$x = isset($_SESSION['foo']) ? $x = &$_SESSION['foo'] : false;
```

Comment: It helped me working around this: https://twitter.com/LorenzoStanco/status/615507406626402304

Comment: Another variation of your last example is: `(isset($_SESSION['foo']) ? $x = &$_SESSION['foo'] : $x = false);`

Answer (score 3):

Let's try:

```
$x =& true?$y:$x;
```

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in...
```

```
$x = true?&$y:&$x;
```

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&' in...
```

So, you see, it doesn't even parse. Wikken is probably right as to why it's not allowed.

You can get around this with a function:

```
function &ternaryRef($cond, &$iftrue, &$iffalse=NULL) {
    if ($cond)
        return $iftrue;
    else
        return $iffalse;
}

$x = 4;
$a = &ternaryRef(true, $x);
xdebug_debug_zval('a');
$b = &ternaryRef(false, $x);
xdebug_debug_zval('b');
```

gives:

a:

```
(refcount=2, is_ref=1),int 4
```

b:

```
(refcount=1, is_ref=0),null
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't.

```
$x=false;
if (isset($_SESSION['foo']))
   $x=&$_SESSION['foo'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The commentary on this bug report might shed some light on the issue:
http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53117.

In essence, the two problems with trying to assign a reference from the result of a ternary operator are:

1. Expressions can't yield references, and
2. `$x = (expression)` is not a reference assignment, even if `(expression)` is a reference (which it isn't; see point 1).