# PHP & references, operator precedence

Tags: php, reference, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

I used the reference operator & like this

```
$root=empty($root)?&$this->_item:&$parent;
```

It catch a exception :

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:

- syntax error, unexpected ':'
- syntax error, unexpected '&'
```

But I written like this :

```
if (empty($root)) {
        $root = &$this->_item;
    } else {
        $root = &$parent;
    }
```

It passed.I want to know why?

I read the php [manual about operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php),& is higher than ?:.

Comment: NOte that in PHP5, using a reference here is unnecessary and `$root=empty($root)? $this->_item : $parent;` would suffice. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php for more.

Comment: Also, references in ternary operators are problematic because of the way the operator is implemented. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389928/can-you-pass-by-reference-while-using-the-ternary-operator

Comment: Thanks Paul Dixon a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use  references with the ternary operator. According to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

*Note: Please note that the ternary operator is a statement, and that it doesn't evaluate to a variable, but to the result of a statement. This is important to know if you want to return a variable by reference.*

So you either have to use it without the references or use the long form:

```
if (empty($root)) {
    $root = &$this->_item;
} else {
    $root = &$parent;
}
```

Comment: Yes,great! That's I want.I read your reference to Manual,I know the really reason.

Comment: Thanks a million. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Try like

```
$root=(empty($root)) ? &$this->_item : &$parent;
```

or like

```
$root=(empty($root) == 'true') ? &$this->_item : &$parent;
```

As **Paul Dixon** said you dont need reference .So you can directly try like

```
$root=(empty($root)) ? $this->_item : $parent;
```

Comment: I just cut a section of the  codes , according to context ,I need use reference,I really want is that :why cant't use reference with operator ?:，please give me a guid via official Manual.Or how do I write like Pure PHP code ?