# ternary operator with ampersand

Tags: php, syntax, pass-by-reference, ternary-operator

I use followed somewhere in my code:

```
if (isset($flat[$pid])) {
  $branch = &$flat[$pid]['items'];
} else {
  $branch = &$tree;
}
```

All ok, but when I want to short it to:

```
$branch = isset($flat[$pid]) ? &$flat[$pid]['items'] : &$tree;
```

I get:

> syntax error, unexpected '&' ...

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389928/can-you-pass-by-reference-while-using-the-ternary-operator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) is an expression, so it doesn't evaluate to a variable. And a quote from the manual:

> **Note:** Please note that the **ternary operator is an expression**, and that it **doesn't evaluate to a variable**, but to the result of an expression. This is important to know if you want to return a variable by reference. The statement return $var == 42 ? $a : $b; in a return-by-reference function will therefore not work and a warning is issued in later PHP versions.

Answer (score 2):

This will work as alternative,

```
(isset($flat[$pid])) ? ($branch = &$flat[$pid]['items']) : ($branch = &$tree);
```

Edit:

The shortest it can go will be two lines,

```
@$temp = &$flat[$pid]['items'];
$branch = &${isset($flat[$pid]) ? "temp" : "tree"};
```

Comment: Very crypty :) I prefer `if` clause in this case.