# Unexpected behaviour in foreach using ternary operator and value by reference

Tags: php, foreach, conditional-operator

Why the following code has the different output in PHP 5.5.* and PHP 7.*:

```
<?php
$foo = ['bar'=>[['item1'=>'value1']]];
foreach ($foo['bar'] ?: [] as $k => &$arr1) {
  $arr1['item1'] = 'value2';
}

var_dump($foo);
```

In PHP 5 value of `$foo['bar'][0]['item1']` will be modified with the `value2`, but in PHP 7 it will not.

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out why this happens. PHP 8 has the same behavior as 7. Here's a simpler code to check this `$values = ['a']; foreach ($values ?? [] as &$v) {$v='b';} var_dump($values);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389928/can-you-pass-by-reference-while-using-the-ternary-operator

Comment: @pmiguelpinto Null coalescing operator was added in [PHP 7](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php)

Comment: @Vladan Your point is?

Comment: @pmiguelpinto Your example includes a null coalescing operator that was added in PHP 7 and did not exist in PHP 5.5.
The OP had ternary operator ?: in his question, which was available in PHP 5.5 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (emphasis mine): *Please note that the ternary operator is an expression, and that it doesn't evaluate to a variable, but to the result of an expression. **This is important to know if you want to return a variable by reference.** The statement return $var == 42 ? $a : $b; in a return-by-reference function will therefore not work and a warning is issued.*

With PHP 5, note how the innermost `&array(1)` is a reference:

```
array(1) {
  ["bar"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    &array(1) {
      ["item1"]=>
      string(6) "value2"
    }
  }
}
```

But with PHP 7, it is not:

```
array(1) {
  ["bar"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["item1"]=>
      string(6) "value1"
    }
  }
}
```

If you remove `?: []`, so the expression you're looping through is simply `$foo['bar']`, then the code behaves the same with both PHP 5 and 7, i.e. the innermost `&array(1)` is a reference.

**TLDR**: I can't say *why* this is, or where the difference is explained, but it seems clear that PHP 7 handles the conditional operator `?:` differently than does PHP 5.